# How to implement a Service Account in a Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am new to GAS and I am struggling to understand how to implement a service account.

**The problem statement:**
**How do i implement a service account to allow a user to run a script that accesses/pulls data from a file in a folder the user is restricted from?**

What the script file does:

1. GAS pulls data from a source file that is in a restricted folder
2. GAS pastes that data into active file, call it "destination file" that is **within the same restricted folder**.

This destination file is shared with Someone who then presses a button to run the script."Someone" will not be in the permissions list of that restricted folder and so they will not be able to run the script at all.

A service account has been created so i have the service account email and private key. I just need guidance on how to implement it in this case. Below is the GAS
Thanks!

```
function myFunction() {

  // Get the data from a sheet in a restricted folder
  const folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('FOLDER_ID');
  var sourceFile = folder.getFilesByName("Example_Test").next();
  var sourceSheet = SpreadsheetApp.open(sourceFile);

  var serviceAccountAuth = getServiceAccountAuth();
  Logger.log(serviceAccountAuth);
  var serviceAccountCredentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.fromJSON(serviceAccountAuth);
  Logger.log(serviceAccountCredentials);
  var serviceAccountSession = serviceAccountCredentials.createDelegated('email id'); // Replace with the user's email
  var service = getService(); // Initialize your Drive service
  service.setToken(serviceAccountSession.getAccessToken());

  var dataSheet1 = sourceSheet.getSheetByName("source");
  var data1 = dataSheet1.getDataRange().getValues();
  
  // Filter the data 
  var filteredData1 = data1.filter(function(row) {
    var nameColIndex = row[25];
    return nameColIndex === "Output";
  });
  
  // Get the existing sheet in this file
  var existingSheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Dest");

  // Clear the existing data in the sheet, and then populate new data
  if (existingSheet1) {
    existingSheet1.getRange(4,1).clearContent();
    existingSheet1.getRange(4, 1, filteredData1.length, filteredData1[0].length).setValues(filteredData1);
  }

}

function getServiceAccountAuth() {
  var serviceAccountEmail = 'email id here';
  var scope = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/sheets'];
  var serviceAccountAuth = {
    'private_key': '00000000000000',
    'client_email': serviceAccountEmail,
    'scopes': scope
  };
  return serviceAccountAuth;
}
```

I tried a solution from Chat GPT but it kept throwing errors like "ReferenceError: ServiceAccountCredentials is not defined"

Comment: About your error of `ReferenceError: ServiceAccountCredentials is not defined`, in this case, `ServiceAccountCredentials` is related to the error. But, when I saw your showing script, I cannot find `ServiceAccountCredentials`. I apologize for this. If your showing script is different from your actual script, although, unfortunately, I cannot know your actual situation, in your actual situation, how about checking `ServiceAccountCredentials`?

Comment: By the way, about `A service account has been created so i have the service account email and private key. I just need guidance on how to implement it in this case.`, in this case, how about checking [apps-script-oauth2@googleworkspace](https://github.com/googleworkspace/apps-script-oauth2#using-service-accounts)?

Comment: @Tanaike i have amended the script to include it

Comment: Thank you for confirming my proposed comments. If those were useful for your situation, I'm glad.

Comment: @tanaike no i meant that, i have added it into my problem statement so you can see what i tried.